# How should I correctly write the term 'get well soon card'?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, syntactic-analysis, generic-term

My instincts tell me that the examples below may be correct; however, I could not find in corroborating sources online.

> She received many 'Get Well Soon' cards.
>
> He opened the mail to find yet another 'Get Well Soon' card.

I would like to better understand the rules relating to this topic.

Comment: It's a matter of style. There is no common rule for this. You can use quotes, nothing at all (the capital letters will sufficiently set the phrase off from the surrounding text), or italics. Or less common stylistic elements.

Comment: You can also hyphenate.

Comment: All ways are correct, there is no hard and fast rule :)